# How to open another activity by just using fingerprint scanner

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio just wants to know is there a way to perform an onButtonclick event from finger print scanner which can send me to another activity.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can You shows us your effort, what have You tried so far?

Comment: Not any great try yet, just have browsed several blogs and android developers page but only came to know about fingerprint authentication for an app, I want to know how finger scanner can be used as an next button to go to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this tutorial [Finger Print scanner](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-add-fingerprint-authentication/)

you can start your activity after finger Authentication